# truffle migrate hanging on Deploying Migrations

Tags: truffle, metamask, ropsten, web3-providers, migration

I am deploying a contract on Ropsten Network,These are my settings

**2_deploy_contracts.js**

```
var SafeMath = artifacts.require("./SafeMath.sol");
var TahaCoin = artifacts.require("./TahaCoin.sol");
var Crowdsale = artifacts.require("./Crowdsale.sol");
module.exports = function(deployer) {
var owner = web3.eth.accounts[0];
var wallet = web3.eth.accounts[1];

//var owner = '0x398DB5039aA7f064a8cBDe5c302E09E2cAc46487';
//var wallet = '0x6A0a14e7aAF404D0E5Cc118ECA740568d936fC9F';

console.log("Owner address: " + owner); 
console.log("Wallet address: " + wallet);   

deployer.deploy(SafeMath, { from: owner });
deployer.link(SafeMath, TahaCoin);
return deployer.deploy(TahaCoin, { from: owner }).then(function() {
    console.log("TahaCoin address: " + TahaCoin.address);
    return deployer.deploy(Crowdsale, TahaCoin.address, wallet, { from: owner }).then(function() {
        console.log("Crowdsale address: " + Crowdsale.address);
        return TahaCoin.deployed().then(function(coin) {
            return coin.owner.call().then(function(owner) {
                console.log("TahaCoin owner : " + owner);
                return coin.transferOwnership(Crowdsale.address, {from: owner}).then(function(txn) {
                    console.log("TahaCoin owner was changed: " + Crowdsale.address);        
                });
            })
        });
    });
});
};
```

**truffle-config.js**

```
// Allows us to use ES6 in our migrations and tests.
require('babel-register')
var bip39 = require("bip39");
var hdkey = require('ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey');
var ProviderEngine = require("web3-provider-engine");
var WalletSubprovider = require('web3-provider-engine/subproviders/wallet.js');
var Web3Subprovider = require("web3-provider-engine/subproviders/web3.js");
 var Web3 = require("web3");

 // Get our mnemonic and create an hdwallet
 var mnemonic = "My phrase  12 words  12 words 12 words";
   var hdwallet = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic));

 // Get the first account using the standard hd path.
 var wallet_hdpath = "m/44'/60'/0'/0/";
 var wallet = hdwallet.derivePath(wallet_hdpath + "0").getWallet();
 var address = "0x" + wallet.getAddress().toString("hex");

 var providerUrl = "https://ropsten.infura.io/";
 var engine = new ProviderEngine();
 engine.addProvider(new WalletSubprovider(wallet, {}));
 engine.addProvider(new Web3Subprovider(new 
 Web3.providers.HttpProvider(providerUrl)));
 engine.start(); // Required by the provider engine.

 module.exports = {
    networks: {
     ropsten: {
        network_id: 3,    // Official ropsten network id
        provider: engine, // Use our custom provider
        from: address,     // Use the address we derived
        gas: 3000000
         }
        },
     rpc: {
     // Use the default host and port when not using ropsten
        host: "localhost",
        port: 8545
        }
       };
```

**important things**

1. Migration was created by my Wallet on Ropsten
2. I have tow accounts on MetaMask
3. I have enough gas "22ETH" in my deployer account
4. i used pragma solidity ^0.4.11 on my contract files

[image]

Comment: Are there any pending transactions on Ropsten for the wallet from which you are deploying your contracts? If so, unless you specify a higher gas price for the new ones, they wont take precedence!

Comment: You can specify gas price, gas limit and other parameters in truffle.js for each network.

Comment: i have't a pending transactions on ropsten

Comment: Is the account that you are using to deploy unlocked at your provider's end?

Comment: i guess it's opened, because i see a deployed migration by my [address](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x4ace6e7b2e4d4b640ce241a0cf52b6d019913cab8987636c4cf595de78e978c6)

Comment: Whats the status of the transaction on etherscan?

Comment: completed, you can see it here: [TX](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x4ace6e7b2e4d4b640ce241a0cf52b6d019913cab8987636c4cf595de78e978c6)

Comment: Its failed. Please see this: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x4ace6e7b2e4d4b640ce241a0cf52b6d019913cab8987636c4cf595de78e978c6

Comment: Always do a Geth Trace. Etherscan has a bug which shows a transaction as successful eventhough it has failed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63647/discussion-between-tahaba-and-zincoshine).

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but consider replacing truffle with etherlime for a swearing-free migration experience.

Comment: Did you try to set a custom provider using hdwalletprovider while unlocking your account?

Answer (score 0):

From line 13 in your migration script, please try the following changes for the subsequent three lines:

```
deployer.deploy(TahaCoin, { from: owner }).then(function(instance) {

console.log("TahaCoin address: " + TahaCoin.address);
return deployer.deploy(Crowdsale, TahaCoin.address, wallet, { from: owner }).then(function(instance) {
```

Please report if this got you a step further.

Comment: do you can edit the file i can't understand place , thanks

Comment: There you go: https://pastebin.com/Ypz36QQ2

Comment: its same problem

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ganache with @truffle/hdwallet-provider for testing, make sure the mnemonic in your truffle config file is the same as the one showed in your Ganache workspace. Mismatch between them is often the reason why truffle deployment hangs.